# Extracting raster pixel values by polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, line

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1 to try and extract the values of raster pixels that individual polylines intersect. I have tried using extract by mask but the wide mask created for each polyline intersects a greater number of raster pixels than just the thinner polyline does, which is unfortunately not very useful for me. Are there any ways to achieve the desired result?

[image: Raster layer (white to green pixels, each with a unique value) with blue polylines overlain]

Comment: Interpolate shape from 3d analyst

Comment: Okay, I tried this, but it doesn't output values of raster pixels on that line. It only gives me a shape length. Is there something I'm missing or supposed to do with this new layer to then get these values?

Comment: Convert vertices to points. Unless you want statistics. If so add Z information

Comment: Frankly you question badly worded, gives no clue about your objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach: Treat your raster data as elevation, and use `StackProfile_3d(in_transect, in_raster, out_tablename, {out_graphname})`. You'll get an output table of z-values plotted against distance from transect origin.

Another: Convert your raster to a point file `RasterToPoint_conversion()`, buffer your transect `Buffer_analysis()`, and find the overlap with `ExtractByMask_sa()`. You'll get a new layer that contains only the cells near your transects.

Comment: The second approach was ideal for my purposes